# changing curly brace as identifier in str.format()

Tags: python, string, subclassing

`format()` method is awesome but I want to change identifier of my choice because I dont want to escape `{` and `}` in my string.

e.g.
`'Hi {name}'.format(**{'name': 'Alok'})` will print `'Hi Alok'`

`'Hi {{{name1}, {name2}}}'.format(**{'name1':'foo', 'name2':'bar'})`
will print `'Hi {foo, bar}'`

In 2nd example `{` and `}` are part of my string so I have to escape them using `{{` and `}}`.

I dont want to escape `{` and `}` or even dont want to use template engine like [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org) etc. How can I change identifier? I guess there would be way using subclassing `str` class.

Comment: `Suppose I dont want to escape { and }` Then what do you want to do? This question is very broad as it stands.

Comment: ''' I guess there would be way using subclassing str class.''' - this sounds bad :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [*String Templates*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) which do $-based substitution instead of {..}

However, the rules are more simple and you lose advanced formatting features like alignment.

Docs: [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template)

```
>>> from string import Template 
>>> s = Template('$who likes $what')
>>> s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
'tim likes kung pao'
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Sure you could probably subclass the str class but i would recommend againt this. This is an example of how this would look like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class FormattableString(str):
    def format(self, symbols, *args, **kwargs):
        start, end = symbols
        prepared_string = self.replace(
            start, '{').replace(end, '}')

        return prepared_string.format(
            *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f_string = FormattableString('Hello [name]')
    print(f_string.format(('[', ']'), name='john'))
```

You can also use the old style of string formatting.

```
'Hi {%(name1)s, %(name2)s}' % {'name1':'foo', 'name2':'bar'}
```

here is a link where the two methods are compared https://pyformat.info/

I would recommend avoiding the old style as possible but if the new style clutter the string then maybe using the old style is better for that particular use case.

Comment: this solution does not solve my purpose because its still using `{` and `}` for substition.  
so `f_string = FormattableString('{Hello} [name]')` will not work without escaping `{`, `}`

Comment: Aaah true I missed that part. You can add escaping in the same fashion can't you?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @blakev's response, you can also subclass `string.Template` and override the placeholder introducing delimiter to your heart's content.

```python
In [1]: from string import Template

In [2]: class CustomTemplate(Template):
    ...:     delimeter = ':'
    ...:

In [3]: s = CustomTemplate(':who likes :what')
    ...: s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
Out[3]: 'tim likes kung pao'
```